# pre-fill forms without id's

Tags: html, forms

So, I was wondering if it was possible to pre-fill a form that doesn't include IDs. If I had a form like this:

```
<form action="" method="POST" >
    <input type="text" name="title" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Would it be possible to pre-fill this form on an already built website, without editing the HTML code?

For reference, the link I would like to do this on is:
https://crystalmathlabs.com/tracker/compcreate.php

Comment: Since it is a php page, you can do it by editing php code. Some of the fields are already pre-filled, so look at those as an example. Alternative is to add JavaScript to your page.

Comment: It isn't my page, which I why I was wondering if there was a way to pre-fill it without having to edit the HTML code. I'd like to know If there is any way of pre-filling it without the need to edit the code on the site directly.

Comment: In that case you will probably have to make a plugin for chrome or another browser that executes your own javascript.

Comment: @al97729 the page seems to use jquery so can i provide you a soln with jquery

Comment: @Deepak that would be useful if you could, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for a jquery solution you can do this

```js
var i=0;
$('form > input').each(function(){
 
$(this).attr('id','id'+i);
i++;

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" >
    <input type="text" name="title" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```